# How do I get the JS from Fomantic UI to work in my Ruby on Rails App?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui, fomantic-ui

I'm looking to get the [Calendar](https://fomantic-ui.com/modules/calendar.html#/definition) javascript functionality to work in my Ruby on Rails app, and it's not, and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong?

I've bundle installed both the `fomantic-ui-sass` and the 'jquery-rails'gems in my application, and put into the `app/assets/application.js` the following:

```
// Loads all Semantic javascripts
//= require semantic-ui
// Load jquery
// = require jquery
// = require jquery_ujs
```

I then put the JS code I found on Fomantic UI into the application.js file, e.g.

```
$('#standard_calendar')
  .calendar()
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things wrong with the above code. Notice that there's a space `// =`  instead of `//=`.

Second, if the semantic-ui is dependent on jquery, jquery should be loaded first.

See [Fomantic UI: $(...).calendar is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61195855/fomantic-ui-calendar-is-not-a-function/61196776#61196776)